# How to Avoid for loops in this Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop

I am attempting to perform Gaussian smoothing on a 2D object in Matlab. Here is a condensed version of my code

```
[m,n] = size(object);
area = m*n;
x = [1:m]; y = [1:n]; [x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:m,
    for j = 1:n,
        z = z + object(i,j)*exp(-((x-i).*(x-i) + (y-j).*(y-j)));
    end
end
z = z/area;
```

This code works quite well, but is *very* slow for large input matrices. I'm wondering if there is a way to make this faster by avoiding the `for` loops? I've tried thinking of ways to speed this up but I can't seem to figure out anything useful.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. It's much cheaper if you generate the Gaussian kernel once, and shift it to the right location. But you should be using `conv2` instead of a loop. Even better is to use [`imgaussfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! I'll look into it. I didn't put it in the code above, but the reason I don't want to use `imgaussfilt` is because it uses only one sigma linewidth for both directions when I need it to be different in each dimension.

Comment: Look at the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html#bunfgk6-1-sigma -- you can use a two-element vector for sigma.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, I didn't realize that. But just so I am more clear, I do not want to do an image blur or filter, but I am doing a Gaussian smoothing instead, hence why I interpolate, sum over all Gaussians, and take the average in the code.

Comment: What you are doing is applying a convolution with a Gaussian kernel, but implemented awkwardly (which is why I said you’re doing it the wrong way around). Usually you’d shift the kernel, multiply and sum to obtain one output pixel. Your version is much more expensive because you’re computing the Gaussian for every pixel, but also because you sum over the whole image for every pixel. In any case, this convolution is a blur filter. Gaussian smoothing, Gaussian filter, Gaussian blur, they’re all the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a vectorized form with no loops. But it uses much more memory and depending on the machine can be slower than the loop. However, most of the computing time is used to compute the variable "kernel" that do not depend on the image. Therefore, if you need to process many images of the same size, you have to compute it only once, and then you might have significant savings in time. I repeat here your code first because I fixed some mixing up of x,y,m,n

```
[m,n] = size(object);
area = m*n;
x = [1:n]; y = [1:m]; [y,x] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:m,
    for j = 1:n,
        z = z + object(i,j)*exp(-((x-i).*(x-i) + (y-j).*(y-j)));
    end
end
z = z/area;
```

Here is a first vectorized form

```
xi=bsxfun(@minus,repmat(x(:),1,area),x(:)');
yj=bsxfun(@minus,repmat(y(:),1,area),y(:)');
kernel=exp(-(xi.^2 + yj.^2));
w=kernel*object(:);
w=reshape(w,[m,n])/area;
```

And an alternative form not using bsxfun

```
xx=repmat(x(:),1,area);
yy=repmat(y(:),1,area);
xx=xx-xx';
yy=yy-yy';
kernel=exp(-(xx.^2 + yy.^2));
w=kernel*object(:);
w=reshape(w,[m,n])/area;
```